# How can I make poetry install the Python version required in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

One thing about poetry seems really odd to me:

When you install poetry, it installs the latest Python version and uses this as a default for all poetry projects. If a different Python version is required as per a per the project's pyproject.toml, the poetry documentation states that you must point poetry to a suitable Python executable via `poetry env use`.

But that means that you need to already have said Python version installed manually.

Isn't the whole point of a dependency manager to install all the right dependency versions for you inside the virtual environment, including the required Python version?

Is there a way to get poetry to install the right Python version automatically or do I have to manually manage the various Python versions that all my poetry projects require?

Answer (score 4):

`poetry` does not install new versions of Python on your machine. It creates a virtual environment using a version of Python you *already* have installed. The purpose of storing a required Python version in `pyproject.toml` is to have that information available for your package's metadata when you build the package.

You (or the package manager of your choice) remain responsible for ensuring that a necessary version of Python is on your machine and available for use by `poetry`.

Comment: that seems so weird. I haven't had this issue. maybe because I've been using anaconda for years and already have the python versions there?